# Laravel and AWS SES: changing email in .env does not reflect in from email address

Tags: laravel, amazon-ses

I am using aws ses to send emails from laravel application and I have changed from email in .env MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS setting

I have also done php artisan cache:clear

yet I continue to receive email from previously set from address

Comment: php artisan config:clear

Comment: I had already tried that. Fixed the issue, I was setting from_address in my application. changed it to get from env.    Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I was setting from_address in my application. changed it to get from env file.